# replace string with its own substring bash

Tags: string, bash, shell, replace, substring

I have string of type

```
.. 23 { ..
```

I want to the result should look like

```
.. { "No":"23" ..
```

I need to do this in Bash Script. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Need a solution with replaces all occurrences of **DD {** with **{"No":"DD"**. 'D' is digit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
sed 's/\(23\)\s*{/{"No":"\1"/g' file
```

**Update:**

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\+\)\s*{/{"No":"\1"/g' file
```

Comment: Need a solution with replaces all occurrences of **DD {** with **{"No":"DD"**. 'D' is digit.

Comment: Thanks saved my day. :)

Answer (score 0):

with bash.

http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-regular-expressions

There is a script on this site which shows you how to handle a regex with matching.

I just copy it to this answer.

```
#!/bin.bash

if [[ $# -lt 2 ]]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 PATTERN STRINGS..."
    exit 1
fi
regex=$1
shift
echo "regex: $regex"
echo

while [[ $1 ]]
do
    if [[ $1 =~ $regex ]]; then
        echo "$1 matches"
        i=1
        n=${#BASH_REMATCH[*]}
        while [[ $i -lt $n ]]
        do
            echo "  capture[$i]: ${BASH_REMATCH[$i]}"
            let i++
        done
    else
        echo "$1 does not match"
    fi
    shift
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Match two-digits followed by any number of space and `{`

```
$ s=".. 35 { .."
$ [[ $s =~ ([0-9][0-9])\ *\{ ]]
$ ms="${s/${BASH_REMATCH[0]}/{ \"No\":\"${BASH_REMATCH[1]}\"}"
$ echo "$ms"
.. { "No":"35" ..

$ s=".. 23 { .."
$ [[ $s =~ ([0-9][0-9])\ *\{ ]]
$ ms="${s/${BASH_REMATCH[0]}/{ \"No\":\"${BASH_REMATCH[1]}\"}"
$ echo "$ms"
.. { "No":"23" ..
```

Match one or more digits followed by any number of space and `{`

```
$ s=".. 25233 { .."
$ [[ $s =~ ([0-9]+)\ *\{ ]]
$ ms="${s/${BASH_REMATCH[0]}/{ \"No\":\"${BASH_REMATCH[1]}\"}"
$ echo "$ms"
.. { "No":"25233" ..
```